# pgSQL update current row in cursor with table name as parameter for the update statement

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

I am writing a function in pgSQL and inside this function there is cursor that goes over a table row by row and if a condition is fulfilled then the row is updated like this:

```
UPDATE company SET code = 5 WHERE CURRENT OF company_cursor;
```

but the table name is a parameter passed to the function and I know I can use
Execute function something like this:

```
Execute 'UPDATE ' || table_name || ' SET code = 5 WHERE CURRENT OF company_cursor';
```

but the problem is that using 'CURRENT OF company_cursor' with Execute function is giving syntax error.

and my function is like this:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION fun(table_name TEXT)
RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE 
 cnt integer DEFAULT 0;
 curr_rec   RECORD;
 prev_rec   RECORD;
 mycursor REFCURSOR;
 query1 text;
BEGIN 
   OPEN mycursor for EXECUTE  query1  ; 
   LOOP
      FETCH mycursor INTO curr_rec;
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

      if cnt > 0 then      
          if  prev_rec.code = curr_rec.code then
               UPDATE company SET code = 1 WHERE CURRENT OF mycursor;
           end if;
      end if;

        prev_rec := curr_rec;
        cnt := cnt + 1;    
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE mycursor;
 return 1;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So can someone please tell me how to use 'CURRENT OF' in this case ?

Comment: A row-by-row update is a bad idea to begin with. But you should show us the complete function, not just a single line ([edit] your question do not post code in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , I edited the question and actually the performance does not matter for me because I will use this function one time and for small amount of data